# Converted HTML5 to WP, How to apply converted classes to new pages (after conversion completed)

Tags: page-template

I've watched numerous youtube videos and have read several blogs but this question never seems to get addressed.

I've converted a local animal rescue group's HTML5 site over to WordPress. The pages that were converted are spot on with the original site and unless you look under the hood (or the slugs in the URL). That's all good. However, when they need to go add new pages and update existing content, they will go straight to the WYSIWYG/Visual text editor (naturally) and not the TEXT editor. So, how would they go about adding new pages and keeping them looking like the rest of the site if they don't know about adding classes to their elements?

```
(e.g. <span class="dogname">Spot</span> is good with kids and is house trained.)
```

Using the Visual editor, they are simply going to type:

```
Spot is good with kids and is house trained
```

but "Spot" would not show up with blue italics text.

Also, not even sure how to TAG this question so I just selected development. If there are better tags to use, please edit as needed.

Comment: You can add your own buttons to the TinyMCE Visual Editor, if you have a bunch of classes that applies to your theme that you want the end user to be able to use. https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles

Comment: That's a good suggestion for the text; however, there are also some layout classes as well. What other ideas do you have? :)

Comment: Well, kind of the million dollar question for web right now - how do you make a CMS thats easy for users to make cool layouts. TinyMCE is garbage for page layouts - many themes use either [shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) (which is a leaning curve, and often finicky for layouts), or [Page Builder plugins](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Wordpress+Page+Builders) like DIVI Builder or Beaver Builder (there's a few others), but they're big plugins and add a lot of stuff. Wordpress sees the need and is making their own, Gutenberg https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg eta 2018.

Comment: Hmmm... One Million Dollars... yeah, I can't develop that solution. ;) I've looked into DIVI. May try it out with this group as a trial by fire approach. Thanks @DavidSword. Sounds like what it boils down to is there is no easy way to do it. As new pages are added and old pages are updated, the old HTML5 layout will eventually fade away.